# Getting double summation into quadratic form

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics

I'm trying to put the equation into quadratic form to prove something with the min-max theorom

$S = [\; \sum_{m=-\infty}^{\infty}\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} r(n-m) w(n) w(m) e^{i(n-m)f} \;]$

so I figure this reduces to the quadratic form as such

$[\; \sum_{m=-\infty}^{\infty}\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} w(n) 
 r(n-m) e^{i(n-m)f}w(m)  \;]$

$[\; W^{T} A W \;]$

but i need to show that the original function S is bounded by the min-max theorom (rayleigh quotient) of the autocorrelation matrix R where r(k) above is the autocorrelation of some input x(n),  n = 0,1,2,3.....N-1

but I'm getting it bounded by the eigenvalues of

$[\;  r(n-m) e^{i(n-m)} \;]$

this would make sense if the eigenvalues of the autocorrelation matrix somehow are related to the fourier transform of the autocorrelation sequence, but I don't think that holds true

Comment: You can write you double sum in the form $w_f^H R w_f$ where $w_f(n) = w(n) e^{-inf}$ and $R_{i,j} = r(i-j)$ so that that $|w_f^* R w_f| \le \|w_f\| \|R w_f\| \le \|w_f\|^2\lambda_{\max}$ where  $\lambda_{\max}$ is the largest singular/eigen-value of $R$ (singular value and eigenvalue of $R$ are the same since $R$ is semi-definite positive)

Comment: Also note that for any signal $y(n)$, the operator $R$ acts by : $(Ry)_n = r \ast y(n) = \mathrm{W}^*\mathrm{D}\mathrm{W}y $ where $\mathrm{W}$ is the FT operator and $D$ the operator multiplying by the FT of $r(n)$. So yes the largest eigenvalue of $R$ is just $\sup_f D_f$ the largest magnitude of the FT of $r(n)$, ie. $\sup_f |X(f)|^2$ where $X(f)$ is the FT of your original signal.

Comment: All this is easier to understand when $x$ is a finite-length signal and $\ast$ is the circular convolution, so we can replace $\mathrm{W}$ by the FFT matrix and so on

Comment: So it seems that S would actually be bounded by $\lambda_{min} ||w_f||^2$ $\leq$ $w_f R w_f $ $\geq$ $\lambda_{max} ||w_f||^2$ as a result of the min/max theorom and since $ S = w_f R w_f $ S would be bounded by the same